# ./configure returns Fortran compiler error?

Tags: configure, compiler, fortran

Attempting to run a configure file for the `fv-fileviewer` gives me this error:

> configure: error: Could not find a Fortran compiler in >/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site>_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

I have never encountered an error like this before: is this a known bug (if it is, I can't find documentation *anywhere*) or just something weird?

Any idea how to fix it?

OS is Manjaro Linux. File is a package for the file viewer from [this](http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/download.html) website.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have solved the problem! To correct this, make sure that the following variables are set to these paths (or wherever your compilers are):

```
export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
export FC=/usr/bin/gfortran
export PERL=/usr/bin/perl
```

This worked for me. For anyone who views this after me, I intend to mark this as correct (it says I have to wait 2 days) but I will probably forget :) so consider it correct.